# Unclear on linking vs compilation

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker

I am aware that many questions exist that address the same issue, but I have been unable to find one that answers my question. I understand the big picture difference between compilation and linking, the former translates each source file into machine code in the form of object files and the latter "links" these object files together in an executable.

However, my confusion arises once we throw in preprocessing into this mix. It is my understanding that if we import another library then *all* of this library is essentially copy and pasted into our code. So even if we are working with multiple files and call one in another, aren't the contents still dumped into the other? If this is the case (which I am sure is incorrect and I have a misunderstanding somewhere) why is the linking even necessary? Aren't we already working with one giant aggregated source file?

Comment: the linking replaces all references by the correct adresses and generates the output (it will expose exported function for example in dynamic library). it will also check your external dependencies also. and it is not a giant single file there are multiple transaltion unit that need to be linked

Comment: `It is my understanding that if we import another library then all of this library is essentially copy and pasted into our code` - this is wrong. And there is no such thing as `import` in C

Comment: @AnisBelaid So the linker only extracts the necessary functions from the imported libraries and checks all the files so there is no error/conflicts in declarations?

Comment: @qrdl I'm sorry I am new to C++, what is the proper terminology if it is not import?

Comment: @APM500 yes , that's one of things that the linker do .

Comment: @APM500 You link with library, and it happens during linking

Comment: Normally you will `#include` headers from a library, which contains only the definitions for it. Then you link against that library, which makes the included definitions point to the already compiled machine code of the library.

Comment: Compiling is translating one language (c, swift,…) to another language (usually processor code) . Nothing more. Linking is building an executable with all the different bricks of (processor) code that are needed : linker find which brick are needed in the list of object file or libraries given to it. That also means that you can change the libraries or object to use different versions without compilation needed.

Comment: @PtitXav Thank you, that helps a lot. I am still unclear though how the preprocessor fits into this and how the preprocessor and linker do different tasks.

Comment: Preprocessor only replace some text in source file with other text according to macros. Then the generated file (it is a temporary file and generally in memory only) can be compiled.

Comment: At the dawn of time (i.e. the 1950s), what we call "compiling" was called "translating" or "coding"; what we call "linking" was called "compiling". These terms made more sense, but then programmers happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprocessing happens before compilation. The preprocessor takes a one or more *source* files, and outputs another *source* file, which is then compiled. The preprocessor is a text-to-text transformer, it has nothing to do with linking.

It is conceptually possible to dump everything in one source file using a preprocessor, and then compile it directly to an executable, skipping the stages of producing object files and linking them together. However this would be **extremely** inconvenient in practice. Imagine a 100,000,000 lines of code program (this includes all the standard library and all the platform libraries and all the third-party libraries). You need to change one line. Would you be willing to compile all 100,000,000 lines again? and when you make an error in that one line, do it again (and again and again and again and again)?

*Some* libraries are distributed entirely as header files. They do not need any  binary files, and are compiled with your program every time the program is compiled. But not all libraries are like that. Some are too big to be compiled every time. Some are not written in C or C++ (they require bits of assembly language for example, or  perhaps Fortran). Some cannot be distributed as source code because the vendors are unwilling to do so for copyright reasons. In all these cases, the solution is to compile the libraries to object files, and then distribute these object files together with headers that contain just *interfaces* (declarations with no definitions) of functions and variables they expose.

`<iostream>` that you mention is a mixed bag. In most implementations it contains both function definitions (templates and small inline functions) that you compile every time when your program is compiled, and declarations of external functions, whose definitions are compiled by the vendor and distributed as a precompiled library.

Answer (score 2):

> It is my understanding that if we import another library then all of this library is essentially copy and pasted into our code.

This is not generally correct.

In C and C++, `#include` directives are mostly used only to import header files, not all of the library. Header files are mostly used to declare functions, and sometimes objects, without defining them. In common language, the declarations in a header file describe the functions but do not define them.

For example, this is a declaration:

```
double square(double x);
```

That says “`square` is a function that takes a `double` argument and returns a `double` value,” but it does not contain the code for `square` and does not tell us what `square` does. (Also, the parameter name, `x`, can be omitted in a declaration.) A declaration just tells us what we need to call the function: We have to put a `double` value in the appropriate place to pass an argument, then we call the routine, and we expect a `double` value to be returned. The compiler cannot generate assembly code for the function from this declaration.

A definition contains the code for a function:

```
double square(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

In most libraries, the definitions are in source files that are compiled separately. The results of those compilations may be made available in various forms of “library” files, such as `.a`, `.so`, `.dylib`, or other files. The library also provides header files that contain only the declarations and not the definitions.

Programs that use the library use `#include` to include the header files. That gives the compiler the information it needs to call the library routines, but it does not import **all** of the library. The definitions remain separate, compiled into the other files mentioned above. To make a complete program, the ordinary object modules of the program must be linked with the library files of the library.

Comment: So the header files just tells the compiler that these functions exist and allocate the correct amount of memory, and the preprocessor is what handles this. The linker is what takes the obj file from your source code and the library you are including (which has the actual function implementations) and puts them together? Is that correct?

Comment: @APM500: Declarations that are not definitions in headers (or anywhere) do not tell the compiler how much memory to allocate. A function declaration just tells a compiler that the function exists somewhere and how to call it. The compiler does not need to know how big a function is to call it. And, if there are object declarations in header files, they may reveal how big the object is (because a complete type shows what size it is), but the compiler still does not reserve memory because of the declaration; it just knows that object is somewhere. Otherwise, yes, the linker puts them together.